# Strange behaviour of singleton

Tags: java, singleton

I assign the reference of singleton object to null.

But still it is calling method of the Singleton class.

Here is my code

```
class Singleton {

private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton();

/*
 * A private Constructor prevents any other class from instantiating.
 */
private Singleton() {
}

/* Static 'instance' method */
public static Singleton getInstance() {
    return singleton;
}

/* Other methods protected by singleton-ness */
protected static void demoMethod() {
    System.out.println("demoMethod for singleton");
}
}

public class SingletonDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Singleton tmp = Singleton.getInstance();
        tmp.demoMethod();
        tmp = null;
        tmp.demoMethod();

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's because the `demoMethod()` is `static`.

Comment: If you get the habbit to acess the class static fields with the class name: `Singleton.demoMethod()` then you will stay clear from such issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the `demoMethod()` is `static` (and being such, it's not part of the state of the instance(s) of `Singleton`, but is rather a part of the class definition)

What happens is that you're not referring to the variable `tmp`, but to the class `Singleton` **via** the `tmp` variable. This should have been raised as a warning by the IDE (usually, Eclipse and IntelliJ do it).

If you remove the `static` keyword, you'll get the expected `NullPointerException`.

Comment: they shouldn't have allowed to call a static method on an instance. And there's a semantic ambiguity - which class is the static method invoke on? the static class of the instance, or the runtime class. the behavior might be counter-intuitive to the programmer.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `demoMethod`, which is a static method - so your code here:

```
tmp.demoMethod();
```

is actually being compiled to:

```
Singleton.demoMethod();
```

That clearly doesn't depend on the value of `tmp`.

This has absolutely nothing to do with being the singleton aspect:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = null;
        System.out.println(x.valueOf(10)); // Calls String.valueOf(10)
    }
}
```

Note that Eclipse has put yellow squiggly lines under those method calls - I strongly suspect if you look at the warnings, you'll see it telling you *not* to call static methods like this. Follow the advice, and you won't get odd behaviour...

Answer (score 1):

The method `demoMethod` is static. It is not bound to any instance of the `Singleton` class. You should change that to an instance method:

```
protected void demoMethod() {
    System.out.println("demoMethod for singleton");
}
```